# Sending a file descriptor from Go to C

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, unix-socket

I am trying to send a file descriptor using an abstract UNIX domain socket but the client side just hangs and never get the descriptor. I am not sure why.

For C code I am trying to use syscalls directly and not some library.

Go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "os/signal"
)

func main() {
    socketAddr := "@myabstractsocket"

    // Create the abstract Unix domain socket
    addr, err := net.ResolveUnixAddr("unixgram", socketAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error resolving address:", err)
        return
    }

    conn, err := net.ListenUnixgram("unixgram", addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening on socket:", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Println("Server listening on", socketAddr)

    // Create a file to send as a file descriptor
    file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Get the file descriptor of the opened file
    fileDescriptor := file.Fd()

    // Send the file descriptor over the Unix domain socket
    fdMsg := syscall.UnixRights(int(fileDescriptor))
    _, _, err = conn.WriteMsgUnix(nil, fdMsg, addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending file descriptor:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("File descriptor sent successfully")

    done := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(done, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    fmt.Println("ctrl+c to continue")
    <-done
}
```

C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

int main()
{
    const char *socketPath = "@myabstractsocket";

    // Create a socket
    int sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Connect to the server socket
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, socketPath, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 1);
    addr.sun_path[0] = 0;

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, strlen(socketPath) + 2) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Receive the file descriptor
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov;
    union
    {
        struct cmsghdr cm;
        char control[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))];
    } control_un;
    struct cmsghdr *cmptr;

    iov.iov_base = buffer;
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(buffer);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_name = NULL;
    msg.msg_namelen = 0;
    msg.msg_control = control_un.control;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(control_un.control);
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    fprintf(stderr, "before\n");

    if (recvmsg(sockfd, &msg, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("recvmsg");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "after\n");

    // Extract the file descriptor
    int receivedFd = -1;
    for (cmptr = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg); cmptr != NULL; cmptr = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, cmptr))
    {
        if (cmptr->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET && cmptr->cmsg_type == SCM_RIGHTS)
        {
            receivedFd = *((int *)CMSG_DATA(cmptr));
            break;
        }
    }

    if (receivedFd == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to receive file descriptor\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems it is nos possible to use SOCK_DGRAM to send file descriptors.

Comment: This one claims it works over SOCK_DGRAM: https://www.mail-archive.com/kragen-hacks@canonical.org/msg00002.html